# How to change a previous Inlinekeyboard message from a normal message

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In my bot, the user is supposed to interact mostly through `Inlinekeyboard` messages.

So, if the user writes some 'regular' message or sends something, I must somehow change the last `Inlinekeyboard` message to continue the process or give him some message.

See the picture below:

[image]

The user wrote some message but I had to create a new `Inlinekeyboard` button with the new message because I couldn't find a way to get the  `message_id` of the previous 'Welcome' button and change it.

My code:

```
HELP = range(1)

def start(bot, update):
    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Help', callback_data='help')]
               ]

    # Create initial message:
    message = 'Welcome.'

    update.message.reply_text(message, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

def help(bot, update):

    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Help', callback_data='help')]
               ]

    bot.edit_message_text(
        text='Help ... help..',
        chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    )
    bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='')

def unknown(bot, update):

    message = 'Please press the Help button for more instructions.'

    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Help', callback_data='help')]
               ]

    update.message.reply_text(message, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))



# Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
updater = Updater(token=config.TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN)

# Get the dispatcher to register handlers:
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(help, pattern='help'))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, unknown))

updater.start_polling()

updater.idle()
```

Best Regards.
Kleyson Rios.

Comment: Well, I came out with a 'workaround' but I believe that might have a better solution. My dispatcher is basically a ConversationHandler. Then I activated in all the handlers the option 'pass_user_data=True' and now I'm keeping track of the message_id inside the user_data, and based on the content of the user_data I know if I have to update the inlinebuttons message or delete the old message and add a new one (to stay at the bottom) saving the new message_id. May I have a better solution than this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *edit the previous messages that the bot has sent*, you need to store their `message_id` (which you already know).

So you can simply do this:

```
sent_message = update.message.reply_text(
    message,
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
)
```

And then you can access it like `sent_message.message_id`

Now for the variable `sent_message`, you can make it *global* or create a *separate file* to handle these variables, or at larger scale, you can store it in a *database*.

Comment: Thanks again Amir.

Comment: @KleysonRios Any time ^_^